# Is this object destructuring or something else?

Tags: destructuring

I'm analyzing code and realized that I can't understand exactly part of it. Please help me with it

```
import {someOffers} from "../const.js";

const createOffer = () => {
  const offers = someOffers.map(({name, price}) => `<li class="some__offer">
  <span class="some__offer-title">${name}</span>
  &plus;
  &euro;&nbsp;<span class="some__offer-price">${price}</span>
  </li>`);
return offers;
}
```

I understand that:

1. We import array **someOffers** from **const.js**. This is a 7-elements array of objects with 3 keys in each **(name, price, type)**.
2. We create arrow function to create the same length **offers** array (as **someOffers**) of template literals markup with appropriate keys **(name, price)** for each element. It is done by map() method, which changes each element of the array using the function, written in parameters:

   (({name, price}) => `<li class="some__offer"><span class="some__offer-title">${name}</span>&plus;&euro;&nbsp;<span class="some__offer-price">${price}</span></li>`)

Can you please decipher these parameters for me. Especially the ones in object literals. Does it has to do something with destructuring?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's destructuring the elements inside `someOffers`.

You could do this for example:

`someOffers.map(offer => <div>${offer.name} ${offer.price}</div>)`

or

`someOffers.map(({name, price}) => <div>${name} ${price}</div>)`

Hopefully this illustration helps picture what's going on.